# Can't overwrite javascript array

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, arrays, slice

I need to monitor results . If the results.length increases, the array will be overwritten and saved. If the length decreases, then the array will be overwritten, but the new value won't save.

```
let playlists = [];
results = simpleMysqlQuery();
setinterval{
    update(playlists, results);
}

function update(playlists, results){
    if(playlists.length != results.length){
        playlists = reWritePlaylists(results, playlists);
    }
}

function reWritePlaylists(results, playlists){
   results.forEach(function(item, i, arr){
      playlists[i] = new Object();
      playlists[i]['id'] = results[i]['id'];
      playlists[i]['name'] = results[i]['name'];
   });
   if(playlists.length > results.length){
      playlists = playlists.slice(0, results.length);
   }
   return playlists;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found de wae!

```
function reWritePlaylists(results, playlists){
   playlists.splice(0, playlists.length);
   results.forEach(function(item, i, arr){
      playlists[i] = new Object();
      playlists[i]['id'] = results[i]['id'];
      playlists[i]['name'] = results[i]['name'];
   });
   return playlists;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you use `slice` and create a new array, the newly created array is no longer a reference to the original array, so the `playlists` parameter in `update` in no longer referring to the same array instance as the `playlists` variable outside the function. Try this:

```
playlists = [];
results = simpleMysqlQuery();
setinterval{
    playlists = update(playlists, results);
}

function update(playlists, results){
    if(playlists.length != results.length){
        playlists = reWritePlaylists(results, playlists);
    }
    return playlists
}

function reWritePlaylists(results, playlists){
   results.forEach(function(item, i, arr){
      playlists[i] = new Object();
      playlists[i]['id'] = results[i]['id'];
      playlists[i]['name'] = results[i]['name'];
   });
   if(playlists.length > results.length){
      playlists = playlists.slice(0, results.length);
   }
   return playlists;
}
```

Comment: Did not help. The array is now not overwritten at all

Answer (score 0):

Please update reWritePlaylists function like below:

```js
function reWritePlaylists(results, playlists){
   playlists.splice(0, results.length);
   results.forEach(function(item, i, arr){
      playlists[i] = new Object();
      playlists[i]['id'] = results[i]['id'];
      playlists[i]['name'] = results[i]['name'];
   });
   return playlists;
}
```

Comment: Did not help. Array overwritten but not saved.

Comment: just modify playlists = []; to playlists.splice(0, results.length);